# Examples of a non-commutative division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

What are some examples of a non-commutative division ring other than quaternions?

Comment: http://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anyone_give_an_example_of_a_skew_field_other_than_the_quaternions_and_their_field_extensions

Comment: The endomorphism ring of a simple $R$-module is always a division ring. I would expect them to be in general non-commutative.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for *division ring* has [an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring#Examples).

Answer (score 2):

Noncommutative domains which satisfy the [right Ore condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition) allow you to build a "right division ring of fractions" in an analogous way to that of the field of fractions for a commutative domain.

This division ring is necessarily not commutative if you pick the domain to be not commutative :) Not commutative right Ore domains are pretty easy to come by: in particular, right Noetherian domains are right Ore. So for example, you could look at the division ring of quotients for $\Bbb H[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many examples in:

R. S. Pierce, *Associative algebras*,Springer-Verlag, 1982